# how to show this has an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I am given that rank of $K=[B, AB,A^2B,\dots, A^{n-1}B]<n$ where $A$ is a $n\times n$ and $B$ is  $n\times m$ matrix. I need to show that there exists a row-vector $x \in \Bbb C^n$ such that

$xA=\lambda x, xB=0$

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to show.  Do you mean "**if** $xA = \lambda x$, **then** $xB = 0$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Observe that the left null space of $[B, AB,\dots, A^{n-1}B]$ is invariant under right multiplication by $A$.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean; I mean what I said.  We could call it "an invariant subspace under right-multiplication by $A$".  If you prefer, note that $(xA)^T = A^Tx^T$, so we're really considering the invariant subspace in the usual sense (i.e. the invariant subspace under left-multiplication) of $A^T$.

Comment: Careful when you prove that $x \in L_n \implies xA \in L_N$.  In particular, you'll need to show that $(xA^{n-1})A = xA^n \in L_N$.

Comment: @Urgent if you're going to edit everything like that, at least change your question so that it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: Note that $Ax$ makes no sense since the $x$'s that we're talking about here are row-vectors.  As I was saying above, if you want to stick to your definition of an invariant subspace, you can think about the column-vector $x^T$ instead.  If $x$ is in $L_N$, then so is $(A^Tx^T)^T$.